# Symbian Audio path problem

Tags: c++, audio, java-me, symbian

I have a symbian app written in c++. I need the MP3 that gets played to be played through the earpiece (or headset if connected). I found this reference to doing it as a java midlet:
http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-E6450E81-BC41-4495-9348-E6FA5ACDB765.html

So my question is:
Is it possible to make the app create an instance of a java midlet and then play the mp3 through the earpiece. or is there a simpler way?

Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Why would you create the java midlet for this? There is an C++ API for playing the MP3 files. Use the `CMdaAudioOutputStream`, which relies directly on the DSP support. All Symbian^3 phones and probably all S60 5th phones have MP3 hardware support. For other devices there are also classes like `CMdaAudioPlayerUtility`, that uses the software MMF codecs.

BR
STeN

Comment: hey, thanks for your answer!
how would i go about changing the audio path using those APIs?
if you could point me in the right direction, that would be great, thank you

Comment: Hi, might be I do not understand your question, but as soon as the headphones are connected to the phone via 3.5mm jack or similar cable on older models, the sound is automatically redirected from the phone speakers to headphones...

Comment: thats great, but i want it to play through the earpiece if there is no headset/headphones connected. do you know if thats possible? thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, but every earpiece must be connected to the phone isn't it? are you talking about the Bluetooth earpiece?

Comment: hey, no i am talking about the normal earpiece that you hear a call out of. the earpiece is part of the phone so it will be connected.